# How do I create an ApiKey from code when AnonymousAccess is set to None

Tags: security, authentication, ravendb

I want to deploy a ravendb server in production.
I don't want it to be accessible by anyone, so `Raven/AnonymousAccess` is set to `None`

I want to use OAuth as authentication, but how can I now setup a new ApiKey?

I want this to be automated, so "install raven with AnonymousAccess = Admin, create apikeys manually, set AnonymousAccess to None manually" is not an option.

Is there a way in which I can either

- Create a new ApiKey even though AnonymousAccess is set to None
  or
- Create an ApiKey automatically and then change AnonymousAccess to None automatically

(and by automatically I mean: in code)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I still haven't found a way to do this properly.
The way I'm currently handling it is:

1. Deploy with `Raven/AnonymousAccess` set to `Admin`
2. Set the ApiKeys manually
3. Redeploy with `Raven/AnonymousAccess` set to `None`

Not the best way, but at the moment, I can't find a better way.

Answer (score 1):

You can do that by authenticating using Windows Auth then setting up the API keys.

Comment: Right, but I can't have a windows account on the server which hosts RavenDB. This is why I'm using OAuth in the first place.